# Struggles with nested for-loop

Tags: java

I am having problems with my code.
The goal with my code is for a user to enter a number which is then used to form
a multiplication-table. 
  For example, if the user enters the number 4, the program is supposed to print following:**

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2  2 * 2 = 4 
1 * 3 = 3  2 * 3 = 6  3 * 3 = 9
1 * 4 = 4  2 * 4 = 8  3 * 4 = 12  4 * 4 = 16
```

This is my current code. Thankful for any kind of help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplicationTable {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {

        Scanner gt = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a number for multiplication: ");
        int N = gt.nextInt();

        for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < N; j++);
                int product = i * j;
                System.out.print(i +" * " +j +" = " +product );
            System.out.println();       
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon after the second `for` loop header and use curly braces for the two statements of that loop.

Comment: Just FYI, the loops are "nested," not "nestled." :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tiny errors in your code, otherwise you are good to go.

```
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++); //<-- remove this semicolon
    {   // <-- use curly braces here for the loop statements
        int product = i * j;
        System.out.print(i +" * " +j +" = " +product+" "); //<--add an additional space at the end
    }
    System.out.println();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that pyramidal structure, you should change the second loop limit to i :

```
for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
```

And remove the semicolon at the end of the loop.